# Docplex objective funtion: Minimize a maximum value

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, docplex, objective-function

I need to minimze the maximum value of a dictionary. How can I phrase the objective function?

example input: A = {1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 7.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 4.0}

So far I´ve tried:

- Count == max(A.values())
- Count == max(A.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1])

model.minimize(Count)

The error I get is: **DOcplexException: Unsupported relational operator:  x282 > x281, only <=, ==, >= are allowed**

Thankful for any answers!!

Comment: *I  need to minimze the maximum value of a dictionary* can you elaborate on it please?

Comment: A is defined as  `for i in I: model.add_constraint(model.sum((a[i,k]*k) for k in K) == A[i])`
i is a part that is assigned to a certain group k.  `a[i,k]` contains if i is assigned to k. The objective is to minimize the number of groups.

Comment: As for any optimization problem, can you define what is the expected inputs, what are the decisions to take (i.e. variables), what are the constraints,  and how you measure quality of solutions (in other terms, what do you maximize/minimize) Thks.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get means Python's `max` cannot handle DOcplex variable objects, which is normal: variables take values only at solve time, so a static computation of max is impossible.

This said, if your concern is to minimize the maximum value of a set of variables, say x_i, use the following trick:

- add one extra variable z
- for each variable x_i add the constraint that (z >= x_i)
- minimize z

At the end of `Model.solve()` z will have been minimized as the maximum value of all x_i.s

Note that DOcplex also has a `Model.max` method to compute the exact maximum of a set of variables, but when you are minimizing, the overhead (in extra variables and constraints) is superior to the above trick.